# What is the difference of declaring a method public or not?

Tags: java, methods, declaration, public

I wonder if there is any difference if I declare the method as public or leave it undeclared like that :

```
void eat() {
  System.out.println("This food is great");
}

public void eat() {
  System.out.println("This food is great");
}
```

Does it have any crucial value to it?

Comment: See the basic difference between [public and default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private) access specifiers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**public** - anyone, everywhere 
**default(no modifiers)** - only in package and in this class

---

You can call method with *public* modifiers from another class / subclass(child-class) / another package / module (if dependency exist)

Otherwise, *default* - you can call this method only from this class( inside calls) and from another package

Answer (score 0):

Member functions are package-private by default. See: [access modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html). There **is** a crucial difference (although to a beginner, the distinction between public and package-private may not be immediately obvious). Understanding access modifiers is crucial in any OO programming language.

Comment: they are private in c++ by default. in java they are package accessible by default

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't disengage C++ mode.

Answer (score 0):

From java docs (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

> If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as package-private), 
>      it is visible only within its own package (packages are named groups of 
>      related classes ...)

I believe this is called `package` if you explicitly state it

Answer (score 0):

A Java method can be declared with one of four different [access levels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html): `public`, `protected`, `default` (i.e. no explicit access level, also called `package-private`), and `private`.

A public method can be called by any object, while a package-private method can only be called by instances of classes which are defined in the same [package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html) as the receiving object's class.